# restful.js - Get request w/ parameters but no ID

Tags: javascript, restful.js

This question is specifically for the [restful.js](https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js) library.

I am trying to hit this endpoint in my api - `/api/v1/applicants`, which should list applicants. I do not have an id to pass to this api call, but I can add a `listing_id` to my parameters to filter results by listing.

For more details on this api endpoint, see docs [here](https://canvas.catalog.instructure.com/api/docs).

I would like to supply this parameter - `{ listing_id: meeting.catalog_course_id, status: 'waitlist' }` to that GET request to filter my results.

`get()` requires an id, `getAll()` just returns everything with no filtering. Is there a way that I can make this api call with the supplied parameters using this library?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the get method method to supply the parameters and the id

```
api.custom('/api/v1/')
  .all('applicants')
  .getAll({ listing_id: meeting.catalog_course_id, status: 'waitlist' });
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, `meeting.catalog_course_id` isn't passed as an id to the api call, it's part of a parameter payload. See my endpoint's documentation [here](https://canvas.catalog.instructure.com/api/docs#waitlist-applicants-listing-applicants)

Comment: I am not sure why this is occurring, but getAll(); is not filtering results by my params. It is instead giving me all applicants records.